# Why REST call with xml payload enclosed with "DeferredDocumentImpl" (spring resttemplate)

Tags: spring, jaxb, resttemplate

I am making a rest call using restemplate and payload is XML. (we are dealing with legacy servers) But When I debug XML at server which is a spring application (legacy, but here irrelevant) , I see that the xml payload enclosed with "DeferredDocumentImpl"

**Client  code:**
This is a new piece which is being added and is straightforward (so may be issue is here) Also I am testing by faking xml payload jsut to check parsing:

```
   .....
String xmlString ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n"
                + "<myroot>\n"
                //node values
                + "</myroot>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml);
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
            HttpEntity<Document> request = new HttpEntity<>(document, headers);




            final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, String.class);
```

when I debugged outgoing call I see xml payload enclosed with "DeferredDocumentImpl"

```
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "POST /myuri HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept: text/plain, application/xml, text/xml, application/json, application/*+xml, application/*+json, */*[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "X-Forwarded-For: value[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Type: text/xml[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Content-Length: 277[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Host: localdev.stanfordhealthcare.org:8443[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.11 (Java/12.0.2)[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "[\r][\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "<DeferredDocumentImpl>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>&lt;myroot>[\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "   &lt;notification>[\n]"
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "      &lt;type>3&lt;/type>[\n]"
/////
    22:17:02.879 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 >> "&lt;/myroot></DeferredDocumentImpl>"
    22:17:08.324 [poolScheduler1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Closing expired connections
```

**Server code :**
This is a  working  production legacy code and it does process xml payload properly .So I dont think there is issue here as it process same xml payload from other clients.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T parseRequestObject(Class<T> pojoClass, HttpServletRequest request) {
    T pojoObject = null;


        String xml = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
        ...
}
```

So here When I debug xml I see the xml payload enclosed with "DeferredDocumentImpl"

```
"<DeferredDocumentImpl>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>&lt;myroot> <..></DeferredDocumentImpl>"
```

Q:I am not sure from where this "DeferredDocumentImpl" is coming and why and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and the error is in  a  because of legacy handling of payload).
It is a REST call but content acceptable is plain text (as xml) not as XML document!

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
   headers.add("X-Forwarded-For", "value");
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
   headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));//This is by default
   HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(xmlString, headers);
```